# Django rest framework one to one relation

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

So I have follwoing models:

```
class A(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  age = models.SmallIntergerField()

class B(models.Model):
  a = models.OneToOneField(A)
  salary = model.IntergerField()
```

Now I want to create one rest end point for there two as they are one to one. So I want following as get

```
{
  url: 'http://localhost/customs/1/',
  name: 'abc',
  age: 24,
  salary: 10000
}
```

Similary, I want to create records and update as well. Please let me know how can I achieve this in django rest framework 3.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just encountered the same problem, it would indeed be useful to make the response structure less tied to the underlying model structure. Here's my take :

## Reading is easy

[Serializer fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments) have a `source` parameter, which can take dotted names to traverse attributes.

```
class ABSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ['name', 'age', 'salary']

    salary = serializer.IntegerField(source='b.salary') # this is your related_name
```

## Writing is ... not officially supported

Validated data will show a nested structure, and the standard create and update methods will choke trying to assign a data dict to a OneToOneField.
The good news is that you can work around it by overriding [create and update](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) methods. Here's an example with update :

```
class ABSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ['name', 'age', 'salary']
        related_fields = ['b']

    salary = serializer.IntegerField(source='b.salary') # this is your related_name

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Handle related objects
        for related_obj_name in self.Meta.related_fields:

            # Validated data will show the nested structure
            data = validated_data.pop(related_obj_name)
            related_instance = getattr(instance, related_obj_name)

            # Same as default update implementation
            for attr_name, value in data.items():
                setattr(related_instance, attr_name, value)
            related_instance.save()
        return super(ABSerializer,self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

Of course, this example is very simplistic, doesn't do any exception handling, and won't work with more deeply nested objects... but you get the idea.

## Another option

You could also [create a read-write flavor of SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields), which would consider both a getter and a setter, however that would probably end up being far more verbose in the end.

Hope that helps !

Comment: I prefer to overwrite update method and take the validated data explicitly, so no handling "automagic" errors are implied (of course at the cost of "more code"). In the example `instance.b.salary = validated_data.get('b', {}).get('salary', '$1000000')`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I came across this and after some research and reading through the [Django Rest Framework documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)
So a quick search I found that you could use the `related_name` parameter for reverse relationships as stated [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations):

> reverse relationships are not automatically included by the
> `ModelSerializer` and `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` classes. To include
> a reverse relationship, you must explicitly add it to the fields list.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>     class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
>         class Meta:
>         fields = ['tracks', ...]
> ```
>
> You'll normally want to ensure that you've set an appropriate
> `related_name` argument on the relationship, that you can use as the
> field name.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>     class Track(models.Model):
>         album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', 
>                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
>      ...
> ```
>
> If you have not set a related name for the reverse relationship,
> you'll need to use the automatically generated `related name` in the
> `fields` argument.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>     class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
>        
>         class Meta:
>             fields = ['track_set', ...]
> ```
>
> Also, see the Django documentation on [reverse
> relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)
> for more details.