# How to save a model in Django Rest Framework having one to one relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a Django model named BankDetail that has a one to one relationship with User.

```
#BankeDetails
class BankDetail(models.Model):
    account_holder_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    iban = models.CharField("IBAN", max_length=34, blank=True, null=True)
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bank_address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    swift_bic_code = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    accepting_fiat_currency = models.OneToOneField(AcceptedFiatCurrency)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The serializer is as listed below :

```
class BankDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for BankDetails"""
    class Meta:
        model = BankDetail
        fields = "__all__"

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['account_number'] or data['iban']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Please fill Account Number or IBAN")
        return data
```

Request Payload :

```
{
    "account_holder_name":"Aladin",
    "account_number":"1239893",
    "bank_name":"Aladin Bank",
    "bank_address":"Republic of Wadia",
    "swift_bic_code":"1",
    "user_id":"1",
    "accepting_fiat_currency_id":"1"
}
```

Now when I'm trying to save the model from my view, I get the following error :

```
{
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "accepting_fiat_currency": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

How can I pass I refrence ob these objects, do I need to manually retrieve them from the db using the id's?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use different serializer for creating/retrieving data in/from database.

Your serializer for creating should be something like -

```
class BankDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Serializer for BankDetails"""
    class Meta:
        model = BankDetail
        exclude = ('user', 'accepting_fiat_currency', ) # Note we have excluded the related fields

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['account_number'] or data['iban']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Please fill Account Number or IBAN")
        return data
```

Then while saving the serializer pass the above two excluded fields. Like -

```
serializer = BankDetailSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save(user=request.user, accepting_fiat_currency=<AcceptedFiatCurrency-object>)
```

> If you are using [Generic Views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) in DRF then I would suggest you to look
>   into **perform_create** method.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR you should define a related model field in the serializer. And don't use `__all__` instead of explicit write all fields. It's my recommendation :)

You should find answer in following questions:

[Post from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878637/django-rest-framework-one-to-one-relation)

[That helped me last week](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/nested-relationships-in-serializers-for-onetoone-fields-in-django-rest-framework-bdb4720d81e6)

[DRF documentation about Serializer relations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send  `"user":"1"`. instead of  `"user_id":"1"`. The same with other  `"accepting_fiat_currency"`